Blazor 8 Delegate Type Could Not Be Inferred
I am migrating my Blazor Server from .NET 7 to 8. Apparently it causes error on calling the function this way:
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check" checked="@isChecked" 
       @onchange="@((e) => AddRemoveSelection((int)i.Id!, Convert.ToBoolean(e.Value)))" />

The compiler says

The delegate type could not be inferred

and highlighted => arrow function with red underline.
Here is the method:
private void AddRemoveSelection(int id, bool isSelected)
{
    if (isSelected)
    {
        // Adding ids to selection
        if (!selectedIds.Any(s => s == id))
        {
            selectedIds.Add(id);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var s = selectedIds.Find(s => s == id);
        selectedIds.Remove(s);
    }
}

Is there any change in Blazor on .NET 8 that disables this syntax?

Use a proper function instead of trying to put everything in the string. It's a lot easier to write, read , debug and maintain. How are you going to inspect the the ID and e.Value now if something unexpected happens? That Convert.ToBoolean will cause problems sooner or later for example. Or you may discover a better way to bind a checkbox to a multi-select property.

It is fine. The check is generated from a DTO with default values, so it will never go wrong like missing values etc. I found this is the easiest way to implement the control interaction. You can just inspect the ID by putting breakpoint, I don't see why are making a big fuss out of it.

I can't generate the error with the code you've show.
The normal issue when you see this is the IDE/Razor Compiler have got themselves in a twist.  I find that restarting the solution normally fixes it. Moving the files outside the IDE [using say File Manager] also often works.
Here's my MRE based on your code.  I've added a refactored version of the input and method that moves all the type conversion to the method.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<input type="checkbox" class="form-check" checked="@isChecked"
       @onchange="@((e) => AddRemoveSelection((int)i.Id!, Convert.ToBoolean(e.Value)))" />

<input type="checkbox" class="form-check" checked="@isChecked"
       @onchange="e => AddRemoveSelection1(i.Id, e)" />

@code{
    private bool isChecked;
    private Data i = new();

    private void AddRemoveSelection(int id, bool isSelected)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    // Alternative method
    // let the method do the type conversion work
    private void AddRemoveSelection1(object? id, ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        //do int convertion
        if (!bool.TryParse(e.Value?.ToString(), out isChecked))
            isChecked = false;
        // Do something
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}


Apparently this error only occurs to components (*.razor) outside of the default  Blazor 8 Components folder (Pages>Components). When I transferred those files into the folder, the problem solved, along together with some referencing corrections.
Hope this helps to whoever encounters the same problem during the migration.

This is not true.  The problem is the IDE/SDK/Razor Compiler get themselves in a twist.  Restarting the solution normally fixes it.  Moving files outside the IDE also seems to often work.  Trying moving the files again.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I tried restarting IDE, but it didnt fix it. It is only when I moved the files into Components folder then the IDE can point out the some referencing errors (the "using" from the .NET 7 structure). Without moving them into the folder, IDE could'nt detect the actual problems.

Have you tried moving the files outside the Components file structure.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I have not. Maybe u are right, it is the Razor compiler went haywire. Happened to another project as well. It was caused by bad namespace referencing.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis can you write down the answer along with some explanation regarding on the IDE/SDK/Razor compilers went ballistic? I will mark it as answer.

I've updated my original answer.

I had this issue when calling a Blazor component and supplying an EventCallback.
The issue arose because I had defined the same method twice.
Removing one of them solved the issue.
